# Cloud Foundry Mutual SSL 502 exception

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, cloud-foundry

We are trying to implement mutual SSL through API gateway for our Springboot MicroService. Call from API Gateway to MicroService fails in PCF with 502 bad gateway. 
502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.

not sure what how to resolve it. I believe this is related to certificate configuration on PCF. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Need to increase the "GB MEMORY PER INSTANCE". The default value is too low for some cases.

For Example: `manifest.yml`

```
applications:
- name: uaa-service
  memory: 2048M
  ....
```

Comment: i dont have memory issue in my application so i am not sure how this will help me